# Can one make CUSP use one's own SBCL?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, cusp

I've already got slime+emacs+sbcl running (SBCL 1.0.23) on my Windows XP machine. CUSP installs with SBCL 1.0.6.

Is there a way to make CUSP use the *existing* SBCL installation instead of its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, I don't have it installed on this computer; but in the options (maybe preferences) section (where Java, Lisp, and other tabbed panels to the left are listed) there is a sub section under Lisp called implementation.

In that section you can select which SBCL binary to use and which image file to load. It doesn't work with the latest SBCL implementation (At least as far as I know).